# Кавычки в полных и сокращенных названиях

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Может ли кто-то квалифицированно помочь со следующим вопросом: как нужно правильно расставить кавычки, если требуется написать рядом полное название и в скобках его сокращенный аббревиатурный вариант, например: "Транссибирская железнодорожная магистраль" (Транссиб) Знаю, что данное название в кавычки вообще не заключается, но если представить, что речь идет о названии компании...

Comment: Без учёта статусных аббревиатур (ООО, ЗАО) вопрос туманный. Нельзя ли конкретно без «если представить»?

Comment: Там будет ООО "Компания такая-то" Само название отличается только буквами :)) Сокращение точно также идет слоговое... Вопрос в том, где ставить кавычки... Так, как есть сейчас (мне кажется, самый правильный вариант), или заключить в кавычки оба названия целиком, вместе со скобками, т. е. поставить кавычки только в начале и в конце... Такое вообще возможно?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ООО «Архитектурная мастерская «Сергей Киселев и Партнеры».

Вот возможные варианты, которых придерживается фирма:

в печати — Архитектурная мастерская «Сергей Киселев и Партнеры»,
в юридическом адресе — ООО «АМ СК и П»,
в переписке — АМ СКиП или СКиП.

Совместить можно, видимо, так: ООО «Архитектурная мастерская «Сергей Киселев и Партнеры» (ООО «АМ СК и П»).

Comment: Добавить ООО - это вариант... Но даже и без него это, видимо, дело вкуса... Но главное, что меня интересовало, - это то, что заключать в кавычки сразу оба названия - сложносокращенное и полное - это невозможно в принципе... Т. е. вариант "Транссибирская железнодорожная магистраль (Транссиб)" не пойдет никак... Спасибо...